# How to auto-register a generic interface to non generic implementations of that interface with Unity

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, unity-container, ioc-container

I have a pattern going in my app.

```cs
public interface ICommandService<TCommand>
{
    public void Execute(TCommand command);
}
```

This interface is implemented by many different service classes. Here is an example:

```cs
public class UpdateWidgetService : ICommandService<UpdateWidget>
{
    public void Execute(UpdateWidget command)
    {
        ...
    }

}

public class UpdateWidget
{
    ...data
}
```

These service classes are being depended upon in controllers and other classes:

```cs
public class WidgetController
{
    private readonly ICommandService<UpdateWidget> service;
    
    public WidgetController(ICommandService<UpdateWidget> service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }
    
    public ActionResult UpdateWidget(UpdateWidgetViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ...
        UpdateWidget command = viewModel.Command;
        this.service.Execute(command);
    }

}
```

If I am to register all type mappings manually I think that something like this would work:

```cs
container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandService<UpdateWidget>), typeof(UpdateWidgetService));
container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandService<CreateWidget>), typeof(CreateWidgetService));
container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandService<DeleteGizmo>), typeof(DeleteGizmoService));
container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandService<LaunchNuclearStrike>), typeof(LaunchNuclearStrikeService));
```

But as you can see there is a convention where all classes that implement `ICommandService<TCommand>` are named `[TCommand]Service` and I would really like to setup some kind of auto-registration by convention. Nothing I have tried so far as worked. My problem seems to be mainly with the generic type argument. Here is what I have so far:

```cs
var container = new UnityContainer();
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var commandServices = assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => !type.IsAbstract && type.Name.EndsWith("Service") && type.GetInterfaces().Single().Name.StartsWith("ICommandService")).ToList();

foreach (var service in commandServices)
{
    var serviceInterface = service.GetInterfaces().Single();
    var genericTypeArgument = serviceInterface.GenericTypeArguments.Single();
    container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandService<genericTypeArgument>), service);
}
```

I'm getting the following error: "'genericTypeArgument' is a variable but is used like a type".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution I've use to solve this problem in various projects, most often around domain-driven event handlers (like `IHandlerOf<DomainEvent>`) or plugin systems.

First, I specify what assemblies I want to include for type discovery.

```
var assemblies = RegistrationByConvention.FromSpecificAssemblies(
    typeof(ClassInAssembly1).Assembly,
    typeof(ClassInAssembly2).Assembly,
    typeof(ClassInAssembly3).Assembly);
```

Then I garner all types that are not abstract, not value types, and are visible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class RegistrationByConvention
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> FromSpecificAssemblies(params Assembly[] assemblies)
    {
        return GetTypes(assemblies);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes(IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies)
    {
        return assemblies.SelectMany(assembly =>
        {
            try
            {
                return GetTypes(assembly.DefinedTypes);
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
            {
                return GetTypes(ex.Types.TakeWhile(x => x != null).Select(x => x.GetTypeInfo()));
            }
        });
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypes(IEnumerable<TypeInfo> typeInfos)
    {
        return typeInfos
            .Where(x => x.IsClass & !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsValueType && x.IsVisible)
            .Select(ti => ti.AsType());
    }
}
```

Finally, for generic implementations like yours, I use `IsAssignableFrom` and `MakeGenericType`. I'd recommend assigning a base class or interface to the `UpdateWidget` and other widgets to make then discoverable.

```
foreach (var matchingType in assemblies.Where((type) => { return typeof(BaseWidget).IsAssignableFrom(type); }))
{
    container.RegisterTypes(
        assemblies.Where((type) =>
        {
            return typeof(ICommandService<>).MakeGenericType(matchingType).IsAssignableFrom(type);
        }),
        WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
        WithName.TypeName,
        WithLifetime.Transient);
}
```

If you just want to solve your error and use your existing code, you'll want to use `Type.MakeGenericType` as in `typeof(ICommandService<>).MakeGenericType(matchingType)`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your commandServices are types, so

```cs
foreach (var service in commandServices
{
    foreach (var interfaceType in service.GetInterfaces())
    {
        container.RegisterType(interfaceType, service);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 var container = new UnityContainer();

var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var commandServices = assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => !type.IsAbstract && type.Name.EndsWith("Service") && type.GetInterfaces().Single().Name.StartsWith("ICommandService")).ToList();

            foreach (var service in commandServices)
            {
                var serviceInterface = service.GetInterfaces().Single();
                var genericTypeArgument = serviceInterface.GenericTypeArguments.Single();

                Type type = Type.GetType($"{genericTypeArgument.UnderlyingSystemType.ToString()}, {genericTypeArgument.Namespace}");

                container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandService<>), type, new TransientLifetimeManager());

                    
            }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.